# extra <option> tags showing inside the <select>

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i am using that code in cake php for creating drop-down list

```
<?php
   $selected = 'Select';
   $options = array('Select' => 'Select', 'New' => 'New', 'Used Dealer' => 'Used Dealer', 'Used Private' => 'Used Private');
   echo $this->Form->select('car_type', $options, $selected);
   ?>
```

output is

```
 select id="UsersCarType" name="data[Users][car_type]">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option selected="selected" value="Select">Select</option>
 <option value="New">New</option>
 <option value="Used Dealer">Used Dealer</option>
 <option value="Used Private">Used Private</option>
 </select>
```

i want to remove this

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank option is there by default:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1430/select

You can pass in an $attributes array to modify that behavior:

> If you wish to display your own default option, add your string value to the 'empty' key in the $attributes variable, or set it to false to turn off the default empty option

So, I'm assuming this would do it:

```
<?php
    $selected = 'Select';
    $options = array('Select' => 'Select', 'New' => 'New', 'Used Dealer' => 'Used Dealer', 'Used Private' => 'Used Private');
    $attributes = array('empty' => false);
    echo $this->Form->select('car_type', $options, $selected, $attributes);
?>
```